# VSCode: “~$ code file” opens new window instead tab

Tags: visual-studio-code

In a Terminal within VSCode, when I type

```
~$ touch deleteme.file
~$ code deleteme.file
```

a new VSCode windows opens up (with considerable loading time), instead of opening the file in a tab of the current window. How can I fix this?

I have the same behavior on

`~$ code -r deleteme.file` or

`~$ code --reuse-window deleteme.file`

[duplicate from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60871805/vscode-code-file-opens-new-window-instead-tab) prematurely closed question]

Answer (score 1):

Reinstalling VScode was the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this depends on your current location in the terminal, but the general answer is :

```
code -r deleteme.file path/to/root/of/vscode/window
```

In case your terminal is already in the root of your VSCode folder, this will do the job:

`code -r deleteme.file .`

The trailing path specifies where VSCode will search for existing windows. But beware that if your path does *not* point to the root of the current VSCode window, you will overwrite the current window (including all tabs) with a new window that just opens `deleteme.file`.